# Android UI - How to create Dynamic UI on XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-xml

I have a weird problem(I assume, not common in Android). I'am working on a product which has its UI "elements" defined by a individual(admin) using our website. Positioning, characteristic and order of the UI elements is decided by the admin. However, type of UI elements is pre selected. Some UI elements are - checkbox, editText,spinner etc. 
Although we handle this programatically, I was wondering if same can be achieved by pre-defined XML(since we know the UI elements we support) and dynamically modify the position and characteristic of the UI elements.

I wanted to do this because it is becoming very painful to manage the UI using the java code.

Any suggestions is appreciated,

SKU

Answer (score 0):

The question is puzzling. You say that your admin defines the UI elements, "however", the type of the UI elements *is* pre-selected? Preselected by who? Exactly what in XML is pre-defined, and what isn't?

If a widget class is defined in XML (a widget is something like , , etc.), you can modify some aspects of the widget's appearance by inflating its layout (which is done automatically for the main layout), finding the widget within the layout tree, and changing the widget's characteristics.

You can't change the widget's *type*. You'd have to delete the widget from the layout and add in a new one that fits into roughly the same space.

Comment: Joe, I am sorry my question was not clear. We give set of UI elements for Admin(customer) to tweak and set characteristics to it. For example we provide EditText, Choice selection, Multi Select, checkbox etc. So admin of the company will then pick any/all of them and mixes it up according to their need which will later be downloaded on their employees devices. Such downloaded data will then be formed as a layout programatically. I hope I have provided enough data.